# How to create/implement/test a new exception in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertraises

I clearly have some fundamental misunderstanding on how to raise exceptions in python. I'm including the simplest example of what I'm trying (and failing) to do. I am trying to create a new exception, and properly test whether it working.

```
import random
import unittest

# Create new class of exception
class LearningError(Exception):
    pass

# Create function
def addition_no_four(first, second):
    """Add two numbers (as long as it isn't 4)."""
    if (first == 4) or (second == 4):
        raise LearningError("We don't take 4s!")
    return first + second

# Properly working example code that tests raising errors
class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = range(10)
    def test_shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, range(10))
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, random.shuffle, (1,2,3))

# My code which tests 
class TestAddition(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_addition(self):
        """Test whether it works for 2 numbers (not 4)."""
        first = 2
        second = 5
        self.assertEqual(addition_no_four(first, second), 7)
    def test_raise(self):
        """Learn how to create an exception and test its implementation."""
        self.assertRaises(LearningError, addition_no_four(2, 4))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Which fails with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 34, in test_raise
    self.assertRaises(LearningError, addition_no_four(2, 4))
  File "test.py", line 12, in addition_no_four
    raise LearningError("We don't take 4s!")
LearningError: We don't take 4s!

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

That doesn't happen (i.e., the example code correctly tests the previous exception. What do I need to change to make this kind of thing happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's just a small change.  When you use *assertRaises*, be sure **not** to call the function directly.  Instead, its arguments need to be passed as arguments to assertRaises.  That allows the assertRaises test method to set-up a try/except before the function is invoked.

```
def test_raise(self):
    """Learn how to create an exception and test its implementation."""
    self.assertRaises(LearningError, addition_no_four, 2, 4)
```

You can also bypass this issue by using assertRaises as a content manager:

```
def test_raise(self):
    """Learn how to create an exception and test its implementation."""
    with self.assertRaises(LearningError):
        addition_no_four(2, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you! I felt like I was about to lose my mind. I figured/hoped it would be an easy fix!